# Pointer to pointer to struct causing segfault using getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, struct, getaddrinfo

I'm using the `getaddrinfo()` function that requires a `struct addrinfo **` to populate with a linked list of results, but I'm getting a segfault when I try the following code...

```
int main() {
    struct addrinfo **results;
    getaddrinfo("localhost", "http", NULL, results); // segfault here
    return 0;
}
```

I'm passing the `struct addrinfo **results` to `getaddinfo()` which expects that type, how is a segfault being caused?

If I change my code slightly to this...

```
int main() {
    struct addrinfo *results;
    getaddrinfo("localhost", "http", NULL, &results); // works        
    return 0;
}
```

my code works fine. Whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` will eventually point to a linked list of `struct addrinfos`, and you can go through this list to get all the addresses that match what you passed in with the third parameter. Function will make a pointer point to a linked list and that's why the address of a pointer is expected. When you pass a `struct addrinfo*` variable's address, it can be made point to the list. Dereference the passed vaiable will be alright, because the dereferenced value is that of the variable `results`. (This explains why `struct addrinfo *results;` and `&results` works).

#### Why the error occured ?

It makes point to the linked list. In the source of `getaddrinfo` from [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c.html)

```
2201    int
2202    getaddrinfo (const char *name, const char *service,
2203                 const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **pai)
2204    {
...
...
2535      if (p)
2536        {
2537          *pai = p; // in your case this (pai) was uninitialized
2538          return 0;
2539        }
2540    
2541      return last_i ? -last_i : EAI_NONAME;
2542    }
```

In your case you provided an uninitialized value. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior. In your case it resulted in segmentation fault.

To clarify further this would also work

```
int main(void) {
    struct addrinfo *results;
    struct addrinfo **results_addr =  &results;
    getaddrinfo("localhost", "http", NULL, results_addr); // works        
    return 0;
}
```

But well the example above is just for the illustration purpose that it is not the double pointer passed was the issue rather initializayion was. *Just pass `&result` which is much more clear and readable.*

Comment: So when I pass `struct addrinfo **results` straight to `getaddrinfo` what am I actually passing to the function?

Comment: @CSStudent.: In your first example you mean?

Comment: Yes, the same as the 1st example

Comment: @CSStudent.: Ok...in your first example you passed `results` which contain some indeterminate uninitialized garbage value. Now when the function does this `*results` then it tries to access that garbage address which invokes undefined behavior. That address might be something that you dont have permission to access to or ... etc. That's why you got seg fault. Segfaults are caused by a program trying to read or write an illegal memory location.

Comment: Ah I see, so I need to explicitly use the address of the `struct addrinfo` I wish to populate which leads to the `**`! Thanks!!

Comment: @CSStudent.: That's one way - more generally you need to pass a valid initialzed pointer. You can look at my second example...it would clarify things.

Comment: Just pass `&results`. The extra variable is useless and confuses the issue.

Comment: @R...: Yes... that's always cleaner and the way to do. but I was showing the OP that what is going wrong in first case when OP showed. It makes my deduction clear. thanks for passing by... and suggetsing. Let me know if there is anything I need to do to make the answer better.

Comment: @R...: Edited. Thanks

Comment: This is an important idiom: when a function takes a pointer as an argument, it means you usually have to pass `&something`, not a pointer variable of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo` function will assign a value to pointer to which the passed argument points to. In the first case you are directly passing the value of uninitialized local variable `results` so it does not really point anywhere and dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior (which manifests itself into crash). In the second case you are passing *a pointer* to `results` local variable, which will point at the first addrinfo structure if function succeeds.